# How to select docs from MingoDB according to datetime field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[Update]

In Compass when I use this for example

```
{ $lt: "2021-09-10"}
```

I get records but in node when I use

```
const d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
const stringDate = d.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Which rests in the same date format but it doesn't return any records

---

I have records in MongoDB with creationTime values like  `2021-09-10 13:20:32` how can I find records before that creationTime? I tried filtering as isoDate but these records didn't return. Below is just an example of the date format. I changed to dateTime format like the example above but no reaults.

```
db.collection.find({$and:
[
{date_time:{$gt:ISODate("2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
 {date_time:{$lt:ISODate("2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}
]
})
```

Comment: could you provide sample data ?
does type of your creation time is date or string?

Comment: Similar data get inserted directly from Laravel to Mongo without using a schema or a model. Other data inserted from node using model can be easily selected.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
db.collection.find(
{date_time:{$gt:ISODate("2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"),$lt:ISODate("2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}
)
```

Comment: Error ````ISODate is not defined```` that's in node for sure using ````mongoose````